# How to prevent a pair of foreign keys repeating in my table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have a table called UserChat which has a user_id and a chat_id as foreign keys. Everything is working out well but I found a bug that mysql will allow multiple of the same pairs in the table. How can I limit it so a pair of foreign keys can only appear once in a table?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `Unique Constraint` for those columns which would prevent insertion of duplicate values, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE USER_CHAT ADD CONSTRAINT USER_CHAT_ID UNIQUE (user_id, chat_id);
```